# FFMpeg - Overlay not being shown when enable=between parameter is added

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using below command to add transitions effect between videos using overlays such that when one videos is about to finish, the overlay gets visible. Before showing overlays, I have to add padding and concatenate videos make one single video and then display overlays.:

```
ffmpeg 
-i input1.mp4 
-i input2.mp4 
-i input3.mp4 
-i transition1.mp4 
-i transition2.mp4 
-filter_complex 
"[0:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video0];
[1:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video1];
[2:v]pad=width=1080:height=1920:x=(1080-iw)*0.5:y=(1920-ih)*0.5:color=black[video2];
[video0][video1][video2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv];
[3:v]colorkey=0x00d800:0.1[t0];
[t0]scale=w=1080:h=1920[tr0];
[4:v]colorkey=0x00d800:0.1[t1];
[t1]scale=w=1080:h=1920[tr1];
[outv][tr0]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t\,7\,9)'[out0];
[out0][tr1]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t\,12\,15)'[out1];
[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[audio]" 
-vsync 0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -map [out1] -map [audio] -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

But above command does not show any overlay video. If I remove enable=between(t, start, end) from overlay parameters, all the overlay gets displayed at video start. I am very beginner to video editing and to FFMpeg. Can anybody guide me what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the log from console:

```
ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I/mobile-ffmpeg:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
      configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
      libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
      libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
      libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
      libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
      libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
      libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
      libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100

I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
    isommp42
        creation_time   : 
    2020-08-12T17:21:49.000000Z
        com.android.version: 
    9
      Duration: 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:08.12
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    17298 kb/s
        Stream #0:0
    (eng)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16309 kb/s
    , SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
    , 
    28.70 fps, 
    29.50 tbr, 
    90k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          rotate          : 
    90
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-12T17:21:49.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandle
        Side data:
          
    displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
        Stream #0:1
I/mobile-ffmpeg: (eng)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-12T17:21:49.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandle
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
        compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : 
    Lavf57.25.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration: 
    00:00:05.97
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    770 kb/s
        Stream #1:0
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
        Stream #1:1
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 368x480, 608 kb/s
    , 
    27.29 fps, 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 120 tbr, 
    12k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input3.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
        compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     encoder         : 
    Lavf55.19.104
      Duration: 
    00:00:13.05
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    2453 kb/s
        Chapter #2:0: 
    start 0.000000, 
    end 13.033000
        Metadata:
          title           : 
        Stream #2:0
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
        Stream #2:1
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 2320 kb/s
    , 
    25 fps, 
    25 tbr, 
    1200k tbn, 
    50 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
        Stream #2:2
    (eng)
    : Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    SubtitleHandler
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transition1.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     compatible_brands: 
    mp41isom
        creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:24:04.000000Z
      Duration: 
    00:00:02.22
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    2445 kb/s
        Stream #3:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2414 kb/s
    , 
    30 fps, 
    30 tbr, 
    30k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:24:04.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
          encoder         : 
    AVC Coding
        Stream #3:1
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 79 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 2020-08-17T09:24:04.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: SoundHandler
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'transition2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
    mp41isom
        creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:21:33.000000Z
      Duration: 
    00:00:02.22
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    2331 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #4:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2298 kb/s
    , 
    30 fps, 
    30 tbr, 
    30k tbn, 
    60 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:21:33.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    VideoHandler
          encoder         : 
    AVC Coding
        Stream #4:1
    (und)
I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 79 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 
    2020-08-17T09:21:33.000000Z
          handler_name    : 
    SoundHandler
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
      Stream #1:0 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
      Stream #1:1 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #2:0 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
      Stream #2:1 (h264) -> pad
      Stream #3:0 (h264) -> colorkey
      Stream #4:0 (h264) -> colorkey
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   overlay
     -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
      concat
     -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x73485c3fc0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 1:1 @ 0x73485c4140] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 2:1 @ 0x73485c4200] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
    [graph 0 input from stream 3:0 @ 0x73485c42c0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 4:0 @ 0x73485c4380] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [swscaler @ 0x7324db9000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [swscaler @ 0x7324876000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0x7332f9a500] using SAR=1/1
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0x7332f9a500] MB rate (8160000000) > level limit (16711680)
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0x7332f9a500] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0x7332f9a500] profile Constrained Baseline, level 6.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 0x7332f9a500] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
      Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
    mp42
        minor_version   : 
    0
        compatible_brands: 
    isommp42
        com.android.version: 
    9
        encoder         : 
    Lavf58.48.100
        Chapter #0:0: 
    start 0.000000, 
    end 13.033000
        Metadata:
          title           : 
        Stream #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1
    , 
    1000k tbn, 
    1000k tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 libx264
        Side data:
          
    cpb: 
    bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
    vbv_delay: N/A
        Stream #0:1
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:       encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 aac
E/Progress: Progress: 3.6918316
D/mobile-ffmpeg: Progress: frame: 1, time: 1002, Pct: 0.036918
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=1.13x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay filter syncs both inputs by timestamps, so that second X of the overlay video is printed on top of second X of the main video. So, with a arg of `overlay=0:0:enable='between(t\,7\,9)'`, ffmpeg will start by aiming to overlay overlay frame with timestamp 7.00 on top of main video with timestamp 7.00. If the overlay video is not that long, there won't be any effect.

The overlay video timestamps need to be modified to create the required sync.

`[3:v]colorkey=0x00d800:0.1,scale=w=1080:h=1920,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB[tr0];`

The setpts shifts the first transition stream to start with timestamp 7. This can now be overlaid with `enable='between(t\,7\,9)'`.

Comment: can you look into this question about FFmpeg as I am quite stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005493/ffmpeg-crash-while-cropping-video