# FFMPEG crash while cropping video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, crop, android-ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to crop a video. I am using [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) as a ffmpeg wrapper in my android app where the user can select any output size irrespective of the original video aspect ratio. Below is the problematic command:

```
-i "/storage/emulated/0/Download/83a2f6_1080p~2.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=304:236:2:2[cropped]" -map "[cropped]" "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/appname/vid_d8ee328d-ec7a-468b-9313-4561dceea33e.mp4"
```

When the execution starts, the application crashes.

Logs:

```
I/ffmpeg-kit: Loading ffmpeg-kit.
I/ffmpeg-kit: Loaded ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-arm64-v8a-4.5.1-20220101.
D/ffmpeg-kit: Async callback block started.
D/VideoEditor:  ffmpeg version v4.5-dev-3393-g30322ebe3c
D/VideoEditor:   Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang version 11.0.5 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d)
D/VideoEditor:    configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/storage/light/projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/storage/light/projects/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libvidstab --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec --enable-gpl
D/VideoEditor:    libavutil      57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
D/VideoEditor:    libavcodec     59. 15.102 / 59. 15.102
D/VideoEditor:    libavformat    59. 10.100 / 59. 10.100
D/VideoEditor:    libavdevice    59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
D/VideoEditor:    libavfilter     8. 21.100 /  8. 21.100
D/VideoEditor:    libswscale      6.  1.102 /  6.  1.102
D/VideoEditor:    libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
D/VideoEditor:  Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/83a2f6_1080p~2.mp4':
D/VideoEditor:    Metadata:
D/VideoEditor:      major_brand     : 
D/VideoEditor:  mp42
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      minor_version   : 
D/VideoEditor:  0
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      compatible_brands: 
D/VideoEditor:  isommp42
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      com.android.version: 
D/VideoEditor:  12
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    Duration: 
D/VideoEditor:  00:02:18.11
D/VideoEditor:  , start: 
D/VideoEditor:  0.000000
D/VideoEditor:  , bitrate: 
D/VideoEditor:  1929 kb/s
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    Stream #0:0
D/VideoEditor:  [0x1]
D/VideoEditor:  (eng)
D/VideoEditor:  : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x808, 1864 kb/s
D/VideoEditor:  , 
D/VideoEditor:  18 fps, 
D/VideoEditor:  18 tbr, 
D/VideoEditor:  90k tbn
D/VideoEditor:   (default)
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      Metadata:
D/VideoEditor:        creation_time   : 
D/VideoEditor:  2022-10-06T11:47:07.000000Z
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:        handler_name    : 
D/VideoEditor:  VideoHandle
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:        vendor_id       : 
D/VideoEditor:  [0][0][0][0]
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    Stream #0:1
D/VideoEditor:  [0x2]
D/VideoEditor:  (und)
D/VideoEditor:  : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
D/VideoEditor:   (default)
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      Metadata:
D/VideoEditor:        creation_time   : 
D/VideoEditor:  2022-10-06T11:47:07.000000Z
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:        handler_name    : 
D/VideoEditor:  SoundHandle
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:        vendor_id       : 
D/VideoEditor:  [0][0][0][0]
D/VideoEditor:  


D/VideoEditor:  [h264 @ 0x7654fe8500] The "sub_text_format" option is deprecated: Deprecated, does nothing
D/VideoEditor:  Stream mapping:
D/VideoEditor:    Stream #0:0 (h264) -> crop
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    crop
D/VideoEditor:   -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
D/VideoEditor:  Press [q] to stop, [?] for help


D/VideoEditor:  [libx264 @ 0x7654fb9af0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
D/VideoEditor:  [libx264 @ 0x7654fb9af0] profile High, level 1.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
D/VideoEditor:  [libx264 @ 0x7654fb9af0] 264 - core 163 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=18 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
D/VideoEditor:  Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/appname/vid_d8ee328d-ec7a-468b-9313-4561dceea33e.mp4':
D/VideoEditor:    Metadata:
D/VideoEditor:      major_brand     : 
D/VideoEditor:  mp42
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      minor_version   : 
D/VideoEditor:  0
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      compatible_brands: 
D/VideoEditor:  isommp42
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      com.android.version: 
D/VideoEditor:  12
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      encoder         : 
D/VideoEditor:  Lavf59.10.100
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:    Stream #0:0
D/VideoEditor:  : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 304x236, q=2-31
D/VideoEditor:  , 
D/VideoEditor:  18 fps, 
D/VideoEditor:  18432 tbn
D/VideoEditor:   (default)
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      Metadata:
D/VideoEditor:        encoder         : 
D/VideoEditor:  Lavc59.15.102 libx264
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:      Side data:
D/VideoEditor:        
D/VideoEditor:  cpb: 
D/VideoEditor:  bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
D/VideoEditor:  vbv_delay: N/A
D/VideoEditor:  
D/VideoEditor:  frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x745d9ff000 in tid 16893 (pool-15-thread-), pid 16696 (videocompressor)


A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/x1sxx/x1s:12/SP1A.210812.016/G980FXXSFFVH7:user/release-keys'
Revision: '22'
ABI: 'arm64'
Processor: '5'
A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-10-09 18:57:38.882598912+0500
A/DEBUG: Process uptime: 1086s
A/DEBUG: Cmdline: com.app.packagename
A/DEBUG: pid: 16939, tid: 20568, name: pool-15-thread-  >>> com.app.packagename <<<
A/DEBUG: uid: 11091
A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x74640ce000
A/DEBUG:     x0  0000007594f30960  x1  00000074640c9a60  x2  00000074640c9eb4  x3  00000074640cac34
A/DEBUG:     x4  00000074640cdff4  x5  00000074671bb2dc  x6  00000000fffffffb  x7  0000000000000013
A/DEBUG:     x8  000000000000000e  x9  00000074640cddc0  x10 0000000000000013  x11 0000007488459ffc
A/DEBUG:     x12 00000074640c9c70  x13 000000000000000e  x14 0000000000007fff  x15 0000000000000013
A/DEBUG:     x16 00000074640cac04  x17 00000074640c7a58  x18 000000746626e000  x19 0000000000000027
A/DEBUG:     x20 000000776541c3b0  x21 00000074671bc4f8  x22 00000074640ca9f0  x23 0000007765422300
A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000027  x25 00000074640cac04  x26 0000000000000028  x27 00000074640c9a30
A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007594f30940  x29 000000000000010a
A/DEBUG:     lr  000000748841a960  sp  00000074671bb290  pc  000000748845a010  pst 0000000080000000
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0000000000359010  /data/app/~~IBCbjRbZBpQ00ORNDFZdxg==/com.app.packagename-5sdOCmN82SjJJTibcsYMpQ==/base.apk!libavcodec.so
```

I don't know what is wrong with the output width and height parameters. If I change `[0:v]crop=304:236:2:2[cropped]` to `[0:v]crop=304:304:2:2[cropped]` with change in height, the process completes successfully. The [original video (1080x808)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17qQsoWyAy53MMg-oaa0OWZ_sItXwBmOJ/view?usp=sharing) is not smaller than the output size. It does not seem to be a problem in the video as I have tried different videos. Any tips on what is missing from my command?

Comment: Have you tried the latest FFmpeg build (v5.1 or even better the latest nightly)? FFmpeg is in constant development, and bugs get sorted out literally daily.

Comment: Yes, today, I updated to FFmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1 which has FFmpeg v5.1 and everything started working properly. But I am wondering how such a common crop functionality can be released with such a huge bug.

Comment: It's just the general nature of open-source projects. Devs aren't getting paid to work on it. Bugs get worked out over time by collective community effort

Answer (score 0):

A sample application will help.

**FFMpegCommandBuild.java**

```
import android.util.Log;

public class FFMpegCommandBuild {

    private static final String TAG = "FFMpegCommandBuild";

    /**
     * device sdk version
     */
    private int mSdkVersion;

    /**
     * codec need or not
     */
    private boolean isCodecNeed = false;

    /**
     * command array
     */
    private String[] cmd;


    /**
     * set sdk version
     * @param mSdkVersion
     */
    public void setMSdkVersion(int mSdkVersion) { this.mSdkVersion = mSdkVersion; }

    /**
     * is codec need
     * @param isCodecNeed
     */
    public void setIsCodecNeed(boolean isCodecNeed) { this.isCodecNeed = isCodecNeed; }

    /**
     * build command array
     * @return
     */
    public String[] getCommand(String startTime, String endTime, String input, String outPut) {

        String videoCodec;
        String threadNumber;
        String presetValue;
        String strictValue;
        String vfValue;
        String[] cmd = null;

        if (mSdkVersion > 15) {
            switch (mSdkVersion) {
                case 16:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 17:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 18:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 19:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 20:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 21:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 22:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 23:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 24:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 25:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 26:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 27:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 28:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 29:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case 30:
                    if (isCodecNeed) {
                        videoCodec = "vp9";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        vfValue = "crop=640:256:0:400";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue,
                                vfValue);
                    } else {
                        videoCodec = "copy";
                        threadNumber = "5";
                        presetValue = "ultrafast";
                        strictValue = "-2";
                        cmd = buildCMDString(
                                startTime,
                                endTime,
                                input,
                                outPut,
                                videoCodec,
                                threadNumber,
                                presetValue,
                                strictValue);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "[getCommand] sdk version is not valid");
        }
        return cmd;
    }

    /**
     * build command string array
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @param input
     * @param output
     * @param videoCodec
     * @param threadNumber
     * @param presetValue
     * @param strictValue
     * @param vfValue
     * @return
     */
    private String[] buildCMDString(String startTime,
                                    String endTime,
                                    String input,
                                    String output,
                                    String videoCodec,
                                    String threadNumber,
                                    String presetValue,
                                    String strictValue,
                                    String vfValue) {
        String[] cmd = new String[] {
                "-y",
                "-i",
                input,
                "-ss",
                startTime,
                "-to",
                endTime,
                "-c:v",
                videoCodec,
                "-vf",
                vfValue,
                "-threads",
                threadNumber,
                "-preset",
                presetValue,
                "-strict",
                strictValue,
                "-async",
                "1",
                output
        };
        return cmd;

    }

    /**
     * build command string array
     * @param startTime
     * @param endTime
     * @param input
     * @param output
     * @param videoCodec
     * @param threadNumber
     * @param presetValue
     * @param strictValue
     * @return
     */
    private String[] buildCMDString(String startTime,
                                    String endTime,
                                    String input,
                                    String output,
                                    String videoCodec,
                                    String threadNumber,
                                    String presetValue,
                                    String strictValue) {
        String[] cmd = new String[] {
                "-y",
                "-i",
                input,
                "-ss",
                startTime,
                "-to",
                endTime,
                "-c:v",
                videoCodec,
                "-threads",
                threadNumber,
                "-preset",
                presetValue,
                "-strict",
                strictValue,
                "-async",
                "1",
                output
        };
        return cmd;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some codecs require the video width and height to be a multiple of 16. 304 is a multiple of 16 but 236 is not. Could this be the case?